# how can I make a filter slider without using jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I am unable of using jQuery-ui for some reason. So I have this slider [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghov3kp8/) and I want to achieve this but without using jQuery-ui.

Here is the code of the slider using jQuery-ui:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
import "jquery-ujs";

$(function () {
    $('.slider__container').slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 20,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#value').val( ui.value );
            filterSystem(ui.value);
        }
    })
});

function filterSystem(value) {
    $("em.match.js-match").hide().filter(function () {
        var length = parseInt($(this).attr("data-length"));
        return  value <= length;
    }).show();
}
```

and here I have the .haml file for the view:

```
.slider.js-slider-filter
  %header.container__header


    .container__title
      %label{:for => "value"} Value:
      %input{:id => "value", :style => "border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;", :type => "text"}

    .container__extra
  .slider__container
```

is it possible to get this only using jQuery?

Comment: "I can't use jquery ui for some reason." Because it won't work? Organizational limitation? There are other non-jquery sliders our there, like https://glidejs.com/

Comment: and the always great: http://youmightnotneedjqueryplugins.com/

Comment: @chiliNUT because I cant make it work with rails. Looks like `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` not doing it's job. And I'm not trying to do a slider for images, but rather a filter slider (range slider).

Answer (score 0):

Although you can find lot more sophisticated examples (like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760239/show-slider-range-value-on-top-of-thumb)) - this is a really basic example you can play with:

```js
// Select DOM elements
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('range');
var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');

// Add event listeners
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  textInput.style.visibility = 'hidden';
});
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  textInput.style.visibility = 'visible';
});

function updateTextInput(val) {
  textInput.value = val;
}
```

```css
#textInput { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />
</div>
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateTextInput(this.value);" />
```

Hope that helps and good luck!

---

EDIT:

Didn't understand exactly your problem. Based on your fiddle i did something like that:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var result = document.getElementById('result');
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
filterSystem();
slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;  
  filterSystem();
}

 function filterSystem() {
  var currentMatch = document.querySelectorAll('.js-match');
  for (var i=0; i<currentMatch.length; i++) {
 currentMatch[i].style.display = 'none';
 currentMatch[parseInt(output.innerHTML)-1].style.display = 'block';
  }
  result.textContent = 'This has '+output.innerHTML+' characters. It says:';
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.js-match {display: none;}
```

```html
<h1>Round Range Slider</h1>

<div class="""slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="2" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <p id="result"></p>  
</div>

<div class="document__body">
  <p class="js-match" data-length="1">1</p>
  <p class="js-match" data-length="2">22</p>
  <p class="js-match" data-length="3">333</p>
  <p class="js-match" data-length="4">4444</p>
  <p class="js-match" data-length="5">55555</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example @A.Meshu , the thing is I am trying to achieve the filter via the slider and that is my problem, you can see it it's `function filterSystem`

Comment: could you please see this and if by chance know why isn't this function filterSystem() working? https://jsfiddle.net/ayj6xtmu/5/

Comment: Sure i'll do it later (not in front a computer right now)